# Masking 1000 ajax post request with better performance

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

We have an application that is installed on some 600 odd servers. This application exposes a web api which gets me version information of the application.

My requirement is to display the version of application on each of the server. I have achieved this in asp.net application by:

1. Writing a web method in aspx.cs page with server name as parameter. This method will build web api URL, invoke web api, get response, build a object and return as json string.
2. I have written an jquery ajax post request for each server name to the above method. On success, built a html table row and append it to table. so that as and when we get response it is shown to user.

This works absolutely fine for say 30-40 servers. But when it increases, it takes lot of time to process all requests (30 - 40 mins). And with multiple users using this asp.net app, we start getting error.

Is there a any other method to achieve this faster and for multiple users without errors?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Applications are maintained by 3rd party. we can't make any modifications to them. only web api url is given to us.

Answer (score 0):

How often is this information changed? If this data is rarely updated, I suggest the following.

Make every of servers to save this information into a shared database table when the server starts. If the application version can be changed while the server is operating, update a corresponding record in a database.

When your service gets information about the application version, get it once from the database table instead of requesting it directly from every server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Applications are maintained by 3rd party. we can't make any modifications to them. only web api url is given to us.

Comment: You mentioned you wrote a web method in aspx.cs page. So, I believe this means you have an access to the server side (possibly your ASP.NET application requests data from another one, isn't it?). So, implemen a static collection (a dictionary) on your server side and fill it collecting data from the remote servers when your application starts. After that generate json data based on cached information only. From time to time (once in 10 minutes / an hour / a day) update the cached data if one of the servers can change its version.